# Three.js Texture Mapping with No Scaling

Tags: three.js, texture-mapping

I'm mapping a texture of dimensions 300 x 250 to a Mesh that is 600 x 20. The texture are being scaled down, distorting the image. Anyway to prevent this?
Ideally, I want to map the texture at 300 X 20, "cutting" away at 20 and above

My code is as follows.

```
var floorTx = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( './walltile/floorTx.jpg' );
floorTx.wrapS = floorTx.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
floorTx.repeat.set(2, 2);
var floorMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: floorTx, specular: 0x050505, shininess: 100});
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(cube, floorMat );
floor.castShadow = true;
floor.receiveShadow = true;
floor.name = "floor";
floor.dynamic = true;
scene.add( floor );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to set the texture's `repeat` property according to the size of the mesh.

```
floorTx.repeat.set(meshWidth / textureWidth, meshHeight / textureHeight);
```

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks! That did the trick. But why though? I looked at the docs and I thought that arg1 was how many times the texture repeated along the x axis and arg2 was how many times it repeated along the y axis.

Comment: Yep you are correct. It's just the mathematics of it. If you have a mesh that is 600 units wide, and a texture that is 300 units wide, you want it to repeat twice to keep its scale, i.e. meshWidth / textureWidth = 600 / 300 = 2 :)